# How to count number of clients form a list certain dates

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this sample sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Zr1ij6KbKbL5IHrVYBNPWmWSWkntZz9amrNBInQY6c/edit?usp=sharing

What I need is count the number of clients from both tab "V" and tab "Ventas" of date :
Today, Yesterday, Last 30 days, This month, Last Month, This month last year

I need the result in Tab "Stats"

any help on this, please?

Comment: you want to count all clients or only unique ones?

Comment: Unique clientes only per date, for example one client can buy In same day multiple items, so I need the number of clients per date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**D4:**

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER({V!B4:B;Ventas!B4:B}, {V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A}=TODAY()))))
```

**D5:**

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER({V!B4:B;Ventas!B4:B}, {V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A}=TODAY()-1))))
```

**D6:**

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER({V!B4:B;Ventas!B4:B}, {V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A}<=TODAY(), 
 {V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A}>=TODAY()-30))))
```

**D7:**

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER({V!B4:B;Ventas!B4:B}, 
 YEAR({V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A})=YEAR(TODAY()), 
 MONTH({V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A})=MONTH(TODAY())))))
```

**D8:**

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER({V!B4:B;Ventas!B4:B}, 
 YEAR({V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A})=YEAR(TODAY()),
 MONTH({V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A})=MONTH(TODAY())-1))))
```

**D9:**

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER({V!B4:B;Ventas!B4:B}, 
 YEAR({V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A})=YEAR(TODAY())-1, 
 MONTH({V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A})=MONTH(TODAY())))))
```